# Getting the cropping and rotation information of an image in a PDF

Tags: pdf, rotation, itext, crop

I have a PDF with a page with an image. I'm using a command line tool to extract this image. The page in the PDF shows only a part of the image, because the extracted image as a lot more "contents" and they are slightly rotated. This happens, I assume, because some sort of cropping and/or rotation was applied to the image when the PDF was built.

Is there anyway, using iText, to figure out the offset and rotation applied to the image? That would allow me to crop the extracted image in the same way and end up with something similar to what's visible on the PDF page.

Comment: Why -1? Feedback appreciated :-)

Comment: The code that extracts the image might help. Seems more likely that height and width are crossed over based on orientation.

Comment: I'm using pdfimages.exe to extract the image (from [Xpdf](http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/)). I see what you mean, but I think that's not the case, as the orientation of the extracted image is the right one. The PDF page is just showing a part of the extracted image.

Comment: Confused. The pdf page you extracted it out of is cropping or some other one that's magically appeared from stage left?

Comment: No, no magically appearances... :) I've updated the question to make it clearer (hopefully). What happens is that the image I extract is much bigger that what I see when I open the PDF. In other words, when looking at the PDF I see the same image, but cropped to a bounding box...

Comment: THose things will be attributes of the image or it's parent. Basically you are going to have to open up the pdf in itext, locate the image and then hunt around, unless you've acrobat professional or similar lying about. There are so many possible controls and favours of them that could be in a pdf, be hard to say who is doing what to whom from here.

Comment: Thank you for the help Tony. When I have a code example that is simple enough to understand I will post another (more technically oriented) question about this issue.